# How to play music a little bit delayed with a real-time Advanced audio analyzer

Tags: html, html5-audio, construct-2

```
Audio.AnalyserFreqBinCount("audio", 0)
```

My game is analyzing the audio levels so that music can affect the game behaviour.

How can I play audio a bit delayed, after it has been analyzed, now the analyzing occurs exactly same time when music is played.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can access the Web Audio API via the framework, you could use the `createDelay()` to create a [delay node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createDelay). The delay is given in seconds.

Then simply:

- Plug source into analyzer node as well as delay node.
- Then connect delay node to destination
- Process the data from analyzer node as usual.

[image: Connection diagram]